# Retrieve non-system folders from RestApi given the folder's relative path

Tags: rest

```
 'YouDomainServer'/_api/Web/GetFolderByServerRelativeUrl('relativepath')/Folders
```

This call returns the system folders like 'Forms' which are not generally visible to the user. How to exclude the system folders from this result?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following query demonstrates how to *exclude* system folders:

```
https://site/_api/Web/GetFolderByServerRelativeUrl('<folder url>')/Folders?$filter=ListItemAllFields ne null&$expand=ListItemAllFields
```

> [SP.Folder.listItemAllFields property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj244887.aspx) is used to determine whether
>   Folder is system or not since system folders are not associated with a
>   List Item.